# How To Get My Solutions Into Windows Problemm Reports and Solutions

Tags: windows-vista

Windows Vista added a Problem Reports and Solutions facility that records software problems, reports them to Microsoft, and then say they collect and make solutions to those problems available to users.

So when my program hits a bug and crashes, the user gets an exception report:

[image]
<sub>(source: [beholdgenealogy.com](http://www.beholdgenealogy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/capture.png))</sub>

This then gets captured by Windows as one of it's problems. Every so often Windows warns the user that they've had problems and asks if they want to look for solutions. It brings up the Problem Reports and Solutions windows:

[image]
<sub>(source: [beholdgenealogy.com](http://www.beholdgenealogy.com/img/probrepsol.gif))</sub>

So then you click on the "Check fo solutions" and it runs through the 255 "problems" that I've encountered for about 50 different software packages, and it results in this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [beholdgenealogy.com](http://www.beholdgenealogy.com/img/nonewsolutions.gif))</sub>

Hopefully, this facility has been improved upon in Windows 7.

But even so, my question is how I can get my solution into the system to direct users to go to my website or contact me if they encountered a problem with my software?

---

Thanks Larry for your answer.

That is a good article that I previously hadn't found. But it is a bit old, referring to Windows XP. I don't mind that, but the key website it referred to: Microsoft Online Crash Analysis (MOCA) at https://oca.microsoft.com/ does not exist.

Even-so, I thought it would be simple to then type Microsoft Online Crash Analysis into Google to see if I can come up with the correct url. The links bring you to various pages in various languages that are part of MOCA. But if you want to get to the starting page, which will have the index on the left, the correct link seems to be: http://oca.microsoft.com/en/welcome.aspx.

That link no longer gives a valid page. The last page in the Internet Archive is [from May 8, 2008](http://web.archive.org/web/20080508022150rn_1/oca.microsoft.com/en/BrowserInfo.aspx), but even it seems to be very nebulous in nature.

Unless I am mistaken and somebody knows better, it appears Microsoft has abandoned their MOCA, even though all their operating systems contain major connections to it.

If someone knows that I'm wrong in this assumption, please add an answer and let me know.

---

Larry pointed out in his now-accepted answer that MOCA turned into WinQual.

How nice  of Microsoft to require registration now if we want to provide them information that will make their tool better. That registration requires a digital certificate which most good programs will have, but it also requires it to be from Verisign and only Verisign. There is some [significant online discussion about this](http://successfulsoftware.net/2008/02/27/the-great-digital-certificate-ripoff/).

Comment: I think you might be more likely to get help from the website serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/expert/northrup_03october06.mspx) shows how to set up OCA for Windows XP, I believe that the steps still apply for Windows Vista and Windows 7.

It turns out that the current name for OCA is "[WinQual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winqual)".  The official web site is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/isv/bb190483.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Larry for that added info. You've not pointed out what happened to OCA. It turned into WinQual. Booooo!

Answer (score 2):

> How nice of Microsoft to require
>   registration now if we want to provide
>   them information that will make their
>   tool better.

The reasoning behind it is probably this:

- Registration is for your own protection: If there was no registration, anyone could have error reports for your app problems sent to them. Even (and specifically) your competitors!
- A Certification Authority (CA) verifies the identity of the ISV (independent software vendor) companies that register with them. Microsoft uses the certificate as proof of identity of an ISV company that registers with Winqual. If they had to do the ID checking themselves, they'd likely need an own department for this.
- The registration is to allow *you* to make *your* application better, to cut down on future support and to keep *your* customer base happy. It's not for "their tool". Correct? :-)

Comment: I guess I should have been clearer about where I'm unhappy. I'm not unhappy that Microsoft requires registration, or that they require a digital certificate. I have one with Comodo, that is accepted by all Windows OS's as a valid digital certificate. But they require you get a Verisign certificate to register with WinQual. The Comodo certificate verifies my identity just as well as Verisign - so why do they require me get a Verisign certificate just ot register? They recently reduced the price of Verisign certificates for registration purpose to $99, but its still bad relations.

Comment: @lkessler: Of course you are right - they _could_ accept other CA's, like Comodo. 
But I still don't think we (you, me, etc.) have a right to complain:
If you develop for someone else's proprietary, closed-source operating system (read: MS Windows), then you have to follow the rules "they" (read: MS) make. Or you can just not participate. [BTW, from what I heard, Apple is no better in this respect.] Did anybody force you to specifically go into MS Windows application development? Or to use Windows Error Reporting services and sign up with the Winqual web site? Well, I believe _not_.

Comment: @lkessler: Another thought: a similar problem is the API - I could also complain that this is not what I would like. Or the video driver subsystem. And so on and on and on... Windows is _not_ a public domain or open source system, and the bits that are "open" and freely available (development tools, driver kits, etc.) are only because the manufacturer made them so. Regarding WER, the manufacturer built a publicly available system which you can sign up for - with a Verisign certificate - and receive problem reports for your application. Much better than nothing, isn't it?